# Setting environment variables with .sh script not working under zsh : how to convert a function

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, zsh, file-conversion

I have to set environment variables in my `zsh SHELL`. For this, I have to execute a script named `clik_profile.sh` (here below).

1. If I `source` it directly on `zsh`, I get the following error coming from :

   `$ source clik_profile.sh`

   `addvar:1: bad substitution`
2. If I do :

   `$ sh clik_profile.sh`

There are not errors but none new environment variables are taken into account (for example by doing :

```
$ env | grep CLIK
```

returns nothing whereas there are `CLIK*` variables environment to export in `zsh`

3. If I do :

   `$ bash clik_profile.sh`

idem to the point 2), none environment variables are exported.

So finally, I don't know what to do to convert this `bash` or `sh` script to `zsh` script
, all of this for having the new environment variables in my `zsh SHELL`.

I think, from point 1), that issue is located in the function `addvar` : I don't know which modifications that I have to applied in this function.

file `clik_profile.sh` :

```
# this code cannot be run directly
# do 'source /Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/bin/clik_profile.sh' from your sh shell or put it in your profile

function addvar () {
local tmp="${!1}" ;
tmp="${tmp//:${2}:/:}" ; tmp="${tmp/#${2}:/}" ; tmp="${tmp/%:${2}/}" ;
export $1="${2}:${tmp}" ;
} 

if [ -z "${PATH}" ]; then 
PATH=/Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/bin
export PATH
else
addvar PATH /Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/bin
fi
if [ -z "${PYTHONPATH}" ]; then 
PYTHONPATH=/Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH
else
addvar PYTHONPATH /Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python/site-packages
fi
if [ -z "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib
fi
if [ -z "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current
fi
if [ -z "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11
fi
CLIK_PATH=/Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01
export CLIK_PATH

CLIK_DATA=/Users/henry/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/share/clik
export CLIK_DATA

CLIK_PLUGIN=rel2015
export CLIK_PLUGIN
```

Comment: `${!name}` does not appear to be a valid zsh expansion; I don't see it listed in https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion

Comment: @Shawn . Thanks for your quick answer. So from what you mentioned,  what would you suggest as solution ?

Comment: I don't remember what that does in bash; might have something later when I have a few minutes to look it up.

Comment: Youpilat13: a reminder that **adding begging messages to your questions does not help**. If you add a begging message and you get an answer, then your helper was going to answer anyway. Again, please refrain from adding begging messages.

Comment: @Shawn That's an indirect variable reference. It uses `$name` as the name of a variable to access.

Comment: The zsh equivalent of `${!variable}` is `${(P)variable}`

Comment: @Barmar No wonder I didn't recognize it; I use namerefs for that in bash instead.

Comment: @Barmar . ${(P)1} did the trick ! thanks

Comment: @youpilat13: I suggest that you rewrite `clik_profile.sh` from scratch, for zsh, so that you end up having two version: The current one for bash, and the new one for zsh. Of course you can copy those lines which work the same in both shells unmodified to your new version.